# Send object in Intend, How to Serializable a ready-made object？

Tags: java, android

My idea is below,but it seems wrong:

```
public class Serializable_APP implements Serializable {

 private Market.App app;

 public Serializable_APP(Market.App app) {
    this.app = app;

 }
 public Market.App getApp() {
    return app;
 }

}
```

The App object is a ready-made and I am not able to change it. Is there any idea to fix it?

Comment: can you sent object like this http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-in-android-app-development ?

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing-object-by-intent-serializableparcelable.html

Comment: Now I would like to try Parcelable : )

Comment: sure and check both the way which may suitable for you to integrate :)